# How do I set the at command shell to bash?

Tags: command-line, cron

How do I change the at command shell from sh to bash?

When running `at`, I recieve the message `warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh`:

```
at 23:33                                                              
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
```

How can I set the default shell to `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at `man at`, it seems like you can't change the shell.

However, you could just launch your commands inside a Bash shell inside `at`'s SH shell, like this:

```
at 01:23 <<< "bash -c 'notify-send \"running from $SHELL\"'"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't change the *default* shell of `at`, it is hardcoded as `/bin/sh` in the source.

The source code of `at` clarifies this, from `at.c`:

> ```
>     /* POSIX.2 allows the shell specified by the user's SHELL environment                                                           
>        variable, the login shell from the user's password database entry,                                                                
>        or /bin/sh to be the command interpreter that processes the at-job.                                                               
>        It also alows a warning diagnostic to be printed.  Because of the                                                                
>        possible variance, we always output the diagnostic. */
>
>     fprintf(stderr, "warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh\n");
> ```

Implementation, from `atd.c`:

```
if (execle("/bin/sh", "sh", (char *) NULL, nenvp) != 0)
```

The man page conforms accordingly:

> at and batch read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time, using */bin/sh*.

That leaves you to recompile your own copy as the only solution to meet your need.

Comment: Well... he could also symlink `bash` to `/bin/xy` (or any 7-character or shorter absolute pathname), and manually edit the correct `/bin/sh` string in the compiled `at` binary to be the new path (not really recommended to anyone who isn't comfortable hex-editing binaries, but possible).

Comment: @mtraceur Or that ;)

Comment: @mtraceur This seems flimsy especially if the string is interned once but has multiple uses -- my point is, the source should be recompiled, rather than editing binaries

Comment: @cat: +1 because that is a good-to-remember technicality in general. But in this practical case, I think if you decide to do such a hack-y solution, then the real question is: Does `at` actually use the string `/bin/sh\0` for anything that would break if it ended up also sharing the same string literal, with this particular change? Even without looking at the source, but knowing what `at` does, I am fairly confident it's likely that the answer is no, it wouldn't actually be a problem. But yes, that is a possibility worth noting.